# Node.js dependencies removing eachother

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to install 2 packages for my Express project. One of them is Express, the other one is Supertest. When i run `npm i supertest --save-dev`, express gets removed. When i run `npm i express --save`, supertest gets removed. What do i do?

Comment: [`npm install`](https://twitter.com/brad_frost/status/996014341592961025).

Comment: I just tried your commands on a blank folder (after running `npm init`), both dependencies were added and both are still visible in the `package.json`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this way :

```
npm i --save supertest express
```

Comment: Wasn't the aim was to add `supertest` as a dev-dependency and `express` as a dependency?